# Need explanation of the result obtained from all_pairs_node_connectivity() function in networkx python library

Tags: python, graph, networkx

What is the meaning of the result returned by all_pairs_node_connectivity() function in networkx python library?

Link:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.approximation.connectivity.all_pairs_node_connectivity.html#networkx.algorithms.approximation.connectivity.all_pairs_node_connectivity

Example graph:
https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/examples/5353/networkx-get-node-connectivity-between-all-pairs-of-nodes